# Triggers update insert

Tags: sql, triggers

It is possible to maintain a table of a database organized alphabetically 
through triggers whenever you insert a new row like this:

```
INSERT INTO Software (name_software) VALUES ('linux');
```

---

```
   name_software
1  windows
2  CAD
```

---

```
   name_software
1  CAD
2  linux
3  windows
```

---

I am using the sybase central. I apologize if my post seems very inconsistent tried to explain in the simplest way.
Thank you.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of rows in a table (physically in the database) is decided by a clustered index. Put one on the `name_software` column and that's it.

But

1) you really don't "need" to sort the data in the table physically like this. It is a database... :) You can sort it by a query.

2) clustered index is most often on primary key and there can of course be only one on a table...

Answer (score 0):

You want to re-order the entire table (and re-seed the identity column for that table) each time you insert (or update) a record?

Why can't you include ORDER BY ASC in your query when retrieving data instead?

Comment: Everything I insert a new software I want it to be in the right position alphabetically. And I was wondering if it was possible to do this in the database to keep organized.